# Angular: search filter on ng-repeat containing external data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Buildings have codes. Example: Main Hall's code is "MNH"

Rooms have numbers that are derived from the building's code. Example: "MNH-101"

In the database, the code is attached to the *building*, not the room. The room just has the building's ID as a foreign key.

So, how can I create a table that contains the rooms written as `[Building Code]-[Room Number]` while still being able to search on the room's 
"full" number: "MNH-101"?

So far, I have this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchRoom">
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="room in view.rooms|filter:searchRoom">
        <td>
            <a ng-href="room/{{room.id}}">
                {{ view.building.code }}-{{ room.number }}
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The combined room numbers display okay and I can search on the room *number*, that is "100", but I can't search on "MNH".

I'm pretty new to angular, so my problem is mostly that I don't know what to google for on this one. Ideally, I want to keep the single search box and I also want to keep the building code and the number in the same column.

A custom filter needed?

Any help?

EDIT:

So, in the controller, I just iterated over the rooms and shoved in the building code.

```
for (var i = rooms.length; i--;) {
    rooms[i].number = vm.building.code + "-" + rooms[i].number;
}
```

Not elegant? Is there a better way?

Comment: If this list of rooms is only used for display purposes, and not saving back to the DB or anything, then it is fine to create a list that contains just what you need for the view, in the format you need it. There is no compulsion to stick to the format sent by the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is better to avoid filters where you can, since they can be run on every digest, even if the list or filter criteria haven't changed. Instead, whenever the filter criteria changes, call a controller function to manually create a new filtered list for the view to bind to. This allows you to use any logic you like.

The basic structure then becomes:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchRoom" ng-change="view.roomFilterChanged(searchRoom)">
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="room in view.filteredRooms track by room.id">
        <td>
            <a ng-href="room/{{room.id}}">
                {{ view.building.code }}-{{ room.number }}
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in your controller:

```
function RoomViewController() {
   // (set this.rooms here)
   this.filteredRooms = this.rooms;
}

RoomViewController.prototype.roomFilterChanged = function (filterText) {
    this.filteredRooms = this.rooms.filter(function (room) {
         // (filter criteria here)
    });
};
```

The exact filter criteria has been left as an exercise for you.

Note that I used `track by` in the `ng-repeat` expression. This is a good practice to get into, since it improves performance of `ng-repeat` whenever the collection changes by allowing it to reuse an existing DOM node for a given item in the collection if it is still in the collection after the change. In this case, the `.id` is a good choice for a uniquely identifying property on each item.